# What is the probability of drawing 6 balls in ascending order from a rotary sphere containing 54 balls

Tags: probability

Probability question in 6/54 super lotto
I wonder, what is the probability of drawing 6 balls in ascending order from a rotary sphere containing 54 balls. For example, 8 14 27 42 47 50

Answer (score 2):

Given any equally likely combination of six balls, there is only one valid way out of $6!$ ways to draw them. The probability of drawing six balls in ascending order thus equals:

$$\frac{1}{6!} = \frac{1}{720}$$